# grant permission to a new role in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, role-base-authorization

We are developing a laravel application, the application has an admin part which is only accessible to the admin users in `routes` file we have:

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace'
              => 'Admin'] , function() {
       Route::get('oldAdminUrl', 'oldControllwe@handle');

  }
```

The `middleware` file's handle function is like

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{       
   if ($this->admin->guest())
    {
        //some code here
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

ad the `$this->Admin` refers to  `Model` called `adminModel` with the following attribute

```
 protected $table = 'admin'
```

Now we need to add a new url to the group of admin urls let's call it 
`newAdminUrl` it should be accessabile for both the admin users and also a new group of users let's call them `editors`

is it a good practice to put that url outside the `admin group` and assign it a new `middleware` let's call it `editorsMiddleware` in additon to `admin middleware` to check if the user who wants to access the `newAdminUrl` is either in editor group or admin group and the editors be stored in another table

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin','editors], 'prefix' => 'admin',      
     'namespace' => 'Admin'] , function() {
         Route::get('newAdminUrl', 'newControllwe@handle');

   }
```

The `EditorModel` which is used inside the `editorMiddleware` has this attribute:

```
     protected $table = 'editor'
```

**The Question:**
what is the right or even good approach to implement it? or anyone has any better idea or suggestion?

Comment: Watch your syntax: `['admin','editors]` missing closing `'` after `'editors`.

Comment: Are you using 5.0 or 5.1?

Comment: You are using a different table, another model, then i would create another middleware for editors. But you can nest groups, so outer group using `editor` middleware. Inner group using `admin`. In case admin passes `editor` middleware...

Comment: @user3158900 I am using 5.1, any suggestion?

Comment: @Iamzozo I can be flexible and store the editors in the same table as admin users are, if you provide me with a nice solution how to handle this case I have no idea how to recognize between the users in that `table, I believe I have to change this code  if ($this->admin->guest())
    {
        //some code here
    }` some way , could you please continue this discussion in answers?

Comment: That doesn't really seem like an admin route because more than admins can access it.  I'd suggest creating a new middleware which takes a role parameter which you could use for both routes.

Answer (score 2):

Really, the approach you've suggested is fine. Create an 'editor' middleware that allows users with 'admin' and 'editor' roles to pass. I have implemented permissions this way in a number of Laravel apps. You might want to consider moving the middleware call to the __contruct() method of the relevant controller just to simplify your routes file and save a line of code for each route, but that's neither here nor there.